# Angularjs -Trigger a directive after one directive finished everything

Tags: angularjs, custom-directive

**My Requirement**

I am generating a template through a directive. Here I will pass some data to generate the template.

I want to call another directive after the above directive has been finished the render.

Comment: "finish render" <- in my opinion there is no such term as "render" except for images in html/js

Comment: What kind of action do you want to perform by calling the other angular directive? A directive is designed to generate a custom HTML element with additional functionality. Be precise and descriptive in your requirements.